# How to add ScrollViewer to UserControl

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I am building an application based on MVVM approach shown in an article by josh smith. One of my user control has many controls (3 data grids and other controls) due to which its size has gone past the size of normal window. I tried adding a scrollviewer to the user control so that the user can scroll to see the hidden controls but the scrollviewer is not working. it is shown as disabled and during runtime the usercontrol only shows the controls visible in normal window size. The other controls are truncated. Can anyone please let me know how to add scrollviewer to workaspaces so that it can work effectively.
I am loading the workspaces suggested by Josh Smith in his article.

Comment: Hard to diagnose without any XAML - can you please update your question

Comment: You still need to set the `Height`/`Width` of your `ScrollViewer` so it knows where it should cut off the content at and start scrolling. Where are you placing the `ScrollViewer`? And what type of control is your `ScrollViewer` placed in? It sounds like your `ScrollViewer` is either placed incorrectly, or its size isn't set and it's allowing the content to stretch as much as it wants.